# Add Card on Click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to dynamically add a row on the press of a button. However, due to my status as new to JS, I cannot seem to figure it out. If you notice in the demo below, nothing happens when you press the green button.This is likely a simple fix, but I just do not have the knowledge to do it. If you'd prefer to use it in CodePen, here is the link as well: [CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/zanderbush/pen/zYBKzzP)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ButtonPro").click(function(){
    $("#okay").append("<p class=RowPro></p> <p class=GreenStripe></p> <p class=InputPro contenteditable>Input</p>");
  });
});
```

```css
.Rectangle {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 1539px;
  height: 1268px;
  background: #f2f4f5;
}

.Rectangle2 {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 105px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 105px;
  left: 270px;
  top: 280px;
}

.Rectangle3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95px;
  height: 8px;
  left: 294px;
  top: 305px;
  background: #1d67ac;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.Zander{
  position: absolute;
  width: 218px;
  height: 39px;
  left: 297px;
  top: 331px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.Rectangle4 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 499px;
  height: 65px;
  left: 270px;
  top: 397px;

  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.Pros {
  position: absolute;
  width: 34px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 294px;
  top: 418px;

  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  /* identical to box height, or 150% */

  color: #41cc90;
}

.ButtonPro {
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  left: 721px;
  top: 430px;

  background: #41cc90;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.Group {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 728.5px;
  top: 437px;

  .Vector {
    position: absolute;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    left: 728.5px;
    top: 422px;

    background: #ffffff;
  }
}

.Rectangle6 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 65px;
  left: 769px;
  top: 397px;

  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.Rectangle_1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  height: 65px;
  left: 766px;
  top: 397px;

  background: #f2f4f5;
}

.Cons {
  position: absolute;
  width: 38px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 794px;
  top: 418px;

  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  /* identical to box height, or 150% */

  color: #ff725c;
}

.ButtonCon {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: #ff725c;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  left: 1222px;
  top: 430px;
  background: #ff725c;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.Group2 {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 1229px;
  top: 437px;

  .Vector2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    left: 1230px;
    top: 422px;

    background: #ffffff;
  }
}

.RowPro {
  position: absolute;
  width: 496px;
  height: 75px;
  left: 270px;
  top: 479px;

  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.GreenStripe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95px;
  height: 8px;
  left: 294px;
  top: 495px;

  background: #41cc90;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.InputPro {
  position:absolute;
  width: 48px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 294px;
  top: 512px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #2C343D;
}

.RowCon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 496px;
  height: 75px;
  left: 769px;
  top: 479px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.RedStripe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95px;
  height: 8px;
  left: 793px;
  top: 495px;
  background: #FF725C;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.InputCon {

  position: absolute;
  width: 48px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 793px;
  top: 512px;

  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
/* identical to box height, or 150% */


  color: #2C343D;
}
```

```html
<p class="Rectangle"></p>
<p class="Rectangle2"></p>
<p class="Zander" contenteditable> Pro Con:</p>
<p class="Rectangle3"></p>
<p class="Rectangle4"></p>
<p class="Pros" contenteditable>Pros</p>

<button id="ButtonPro" class="ButtonPro"></button>

<div class="Group">
  <div class="Vector">
    <svg width="18" height="17" viewBox="0 0 18 17" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11.125 6.375V0H6.875V6.375H0.5V10.625H6.875V17H11.125V10.625H17.5V6.375H11.125Z" fill="white" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>

<p class="Rectangle6"></p>

<p class="Rectangle_1"></p>

<p class="Cons" contenteditable>Cons</p>

<button class="ButtonCon"></button>

<div class="Group2">
  <div class="Vector2">
    <svg width="18" height="17" viewBox="0 0 18 17" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11.125 6.375V0H6.875V6.375H0.5V10.625H6.875V17H11.125V10.625H17.5V6.375H11.125Z" fill="white" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>

<p class="RowPro"></p>
<p class="GreenStripe"></p>
<p class="InputPro" id="okay" contenteditable>Input</p>

<p class="Rectangle_2"></p>

<p class="RowCon"></p>

<p class="RedStripe"></p>

<p class="InputCon">Input</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to dynamically add the cards that say "Input" and have the stripes?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, you are correct. @BucksBall

Comment: For anyone wanting to complete the solution: `rowpro` has absolute positioning, which positions each row on top of the other. Also the button can't be clicked because the SVG is absolutely positioned in such a way that the click event can't be triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works (I think as intended), the problem is that it is not easy to press the button, because you have a `div` element on top. You just need to set `pointer-events` to `none` in that element. I have added css code for the `Group` class. Incidentally, you may want to set the other button to the same class (meaning change `Group2` to `Group`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ButtonPro").click(function(){
    $("#okay").append("<p class=RowPro></p> <p class=GreenStripe></p> <p class=InputPro contenteditable>Input</p>");
  });
});
```

```css
.Rectangle {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 1539px;
  height: 1268px;
  background: #f2f4f5;
}

.Rectangle2 {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 105px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 105px;
  left: 270px;
  top: 280px;
}
.Group{
   pointer-events: none;
}

.Rectangle3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95px;
  height: 8px;
  left: 294px;
  top: 305px;
  background: #1d67ac;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.Zander{
  position: absolute;
  width: 218px;
  height: 39px;
  left: 297px;
  top: 331px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.Rectangle4 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 499px;
  height: 65px;
  left: 270px;
  top: 397px;

  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.Pros {
  position: absolute;
  width: 34px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 294px;
  top: 418px;

  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  /* identical to box height, or 150% */

  color: #41cc90;
}

.ButtonPro {
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  left: 721px;
  top: 430px;

  background: #41cc90;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.Group {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 728.5px;
  top: 437px;

  .Vector {
    position: absolute;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    left: 728.5px;
    top: 422px;

    background: #ffffff;
  }
}

.Rectangle6 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 65px;
  left: 769px;
  top: 397px;

  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.Rectangle_1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  height: 65px;
  left: 766px;
  top: 397px;

  background: #f2f4f5;
}

.Cons {
  position: absolute;
  width: 38px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 794px;
  top: 418px;

  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  /* identical to box height, or 150% */

  color: #ff725c;
}

.ButtonCon {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: #ff725c;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  left: 1222px;
  top: 430px;
  background: #ff725c;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.Group2 {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 1229px;
  top: 437px;

  .Vector2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    left: 1230px;
    top: 422px;

    background: #ffffff;
  }
}

.RowPro {
  position: absolute;
  width: 496px;
  height: 75px;
  left: 270px;
  top: 479px;

  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.GreenStripe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95px;
  height: 8px;
  left: 294px;
  top: 495px;

  background: #41cc90;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.InputPro {
  position:absolute;
  width: 48px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 294px;
  top: 512px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #2C343D;
}

.RowCon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 496px;
  height: 75px;
  left: 769px;
  top: 479px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.RedStripe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95px;
  height: 8px;
  left: 793px;
  top: 495px;
  background: #FF725C;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.InputCon {

  position: absolute;
  width: 48px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 793px;
  top: 512px;

  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
/* identical to box height, or 150% */


  color: #2C343D;
}
```

```html
<p class="Rectangle"></p>
<p class="Rectangle2"></p>
<p class="Zander" contenteditable> Pro Con:</p>
<p class="Rectangle3"></p>
<p class="Rectangle4"></p>
<p class="Pros" contenteditable>Pros</p>

<button id="ButtonPro" class="ButtonPro"></button>

<div class="Group">
  <div class="Vector">
    <svg width="18" height="17" viewBox="0 0 18 17" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11.125 6.375V0H6.875V6.375H0.5V10.625H6.875V17H11.125V10.625H17.5V6.375H11.125Z" fill="white" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>

<p class="Rectangle6"></p>

<p class="Rectangle_1"></p>

<p class="Cons" contenteditable>Cons</p>

<button class="ButtonCon"></button>

<div class="Group2">
  <div class="Vector2">
    <svg width="18" height="17" viewBox="0 0 18 17" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11.125 6.375V0H6.875V6.375H0.5V10.625H6.875V17H11.125V10.625H17.5V6.375H11.125Z" fill="white" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>

<p class="RowPro"></p>
<p class="GreenStripe"></p>
<p class="InputPro" id="okay" contenteditable>Input</p>

<p class="Rectangle_2"></p>

<p class="RowCon"></p>

<p class="RedStripe"></p>

<p class="InputCon">Input</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT after comment:
If you do not need absolute positioning, the jQuery code is kept simple. In that setting, each card is relatively positioned in an absolutely positioned div (`#okay`). Notice that now `.GreenStripe` and `.InputPro` are inside `.RowPro`. I have kept the approximate layout, but you would need to tweak `top` and `left` for `.GreenStripe` and `InputPro`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ButtonPro").click(function(){
    $("#okay").append("<div class='RowPro'><div class='GreenStripe'></div><div class='InputPro' contenteditable>Input</div></div>");
  });
});
```

```css
.Rectangle {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 1539px;
  height: 1268px;
  background: #f2f4f5;
}

.Rectangle2 {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 105px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 105px;
  left: 270px;
  top: 280px;
}
.Group{
   pointer-events: none;
}

.Rectangle3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95px;
  height: 8px;
  left: 294px;
  top: 305px;
  background: #1d67ac;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.Zander{
  position: absolute;
  width: 218px;
  height: 39px;
  left: 297px;
  top: 331px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.Rectangle4 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 499px;
  height: 65px;
  left: 270px;
  top: 397px;

  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.Pros {
  position: absolute;
  width: 34px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 294px;
  top: 418px;

  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  /* identical to box height, or 150% */

  color: #41cc90;
}

.ButtonPro {
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  left: 721px;
  top: 430px;

  background: #41cc90;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.Group {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 728.5px;
  top: 437px;

  .Vector {
    position: absolute;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    left: 728.5px;
    top: 422px;

    background: #ffffff;
  }
}

.Rectangle6 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 65px;
  left: 769px;
  top: 397px;

  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.Rectangle_1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  height: 65px;
  left: 766px;
  top: 397px;

  background: #f2f4f5;
}

.Cons {
  position: absolute;
  width: 38px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 794px;
  top: 418px;

  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  /* identical to box height, or 150% */

  color: #ff725c;
}

.ButtonCon {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: #ff725c;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  left: 1222px;
  top: 430px;
  background: #ff725c;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.Group2 {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 1229px;
  top: 437px;

  .Vector2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    left: 1230px;
    top: 422px;

    background: #ffffff;
  }
}

.RowPro {
  width: 496px;
  height: 75px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.GreenStripe {
  position: relative;
  width: 95px;
  height: 8px;
  top: 16px;
  left: 16px;
  background: #41cc90;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.InputPro {
  width: 500px;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  left: 16px;
  top: 33px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #2C343D;
}

.RowCon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 496px;
  height: 75px;
  left: 769px;
  top: 479px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.RedStripe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95px;
  height: 8px;
  left: 793px;
  top: 495px;
  background: #FF725C;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.InputCon {

  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 793px;
  top: 512px;

  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
/* identical to box height, or 150% */


  color: #2C343D;
}

#okay{
  position: absolute;
  width: 496px;
  height: 123px;
  left: 270px;
  top: 479px;
}
```

```html
<p class="Rectangle"></p>
<p class="Rectangle2"></p>
<p class="Zander" contenteditable> Pro Con:</p>
<p class="Rectangle3"></p>
<p class="Rectangle4"></p>
<p class="Pros" contenteditable>Pros</p>

<button id="ButtonPro" class="ButtonPro"></button>

<div class="Group">
  <div class="Vector">
    <svg width="18" height="17" viewBox="0 0 18 17" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11.125 6.375V0H6.875V6.375H0.5V10.625H6.875V17H11.125V10.625H17.5V6.375H11.125Z" fill="white" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>

<p class="Rectangle6"></p>

<p class="Rectangle_1"></p>

<p class="Cons" contenteditable>Cons</p>

<button class="ButtonCon"></button>

<div class="Group2">
  <div class="Vector2">
    <svg width="18" height="17" viewBox="0 0 18 17" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11.125 6.375V0H6.875V6.375H0.5V10.625H6.875V17H11.125V10.625H17.5V6.375H11.125Z" fill="white" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="okay">
<div class="RowPro"><div class="GreenStripe"></div><div class="InputPro" contenteditable>Input</div></div>
</div>
<p class="Rectangle_2"></p>

<p class="RowCon"></p>

<p class="RedStripe"></p>

<p class="InputCon">Input</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I should've been more clear in my question. Is it possible to dynamically add new rows? It seems that the code you provided allows me to add one new row. I'm also not exactly sure how to get the new row to be in line with the green side. I may have worded this poorly, so feel free to clarify if you need. @vqf

Comment: The thing is, you are adding those cards, but your `position` property is `absolute`. That means that you are adding it to the same place in the page every time. Is absolute positioning important for your design?

Comment: I have added a possible strategy if absolute positioning is not important.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some guidance: try y = mx + b. That should give you a foundation to work off of.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: That's not appropriate for the site.

Comment: What are you trying to answer with this?